# Как подвязаться на лайк фото вконтакте и узнать,как только это фото кто-то лайкнул?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как подвязаться на лайк фото вконтакте и узнать,как только это фото кто-то лайкнул?
Я создал приложение и там есть кнопка "Мне нравится" (либо другой вариант- выложу просто фотку вконтакте) и нужно, что б мой сервер сразу же знал, что фото лайкнули.
Можно получить лайки  https://vk.com/dev/likes.getList , но хочется, что б как вконтакте они обновлялись сами.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="openapi.js"></script>

<div id="vk_like"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

      VK.init({apiId: 5309489});


    VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like", {type: "button"},55);
    VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.liked", function f()
    {
        alert ("Thank you for your like.");
    });

</script>  //этот код не работает в режиме реального времени
```

Как подобное сделать?

Comment: что значит "обновлялись сами" ?

Comment: Что б изменения сразу же были видны. Сейчас нашёл https://vk.com/dev/openapi_observer , но не могу на примере, где много кнопок "мне нравится"- сделать

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.
Просто этот код разместить непосредственно там. где человек кликает. А я пытался разместить на другой странице и получать там данные. когда пользователь кликнул.

```
VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.liked", function f()
    {
        //Здесь отправляем данные на свой сервер
    });
```

Comment: Аккуратно с таким решением, для лайков из других мест работать не будет, и пользователь сможет отправить данные без лайка, если захочет

Comment: ok. Ну это единственный вариант, который я придумал